# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

I've got a script that's giving me headaches on a particular server.

I keep getting this error:

**Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Even though I've edited php.ini to this:

```
max_execution_time = 300     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 600    ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 96M    ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (16MB)
```

Where would the 67108864 bytes limit be coming from?

Comment: Somewhere there's a memory limit of `64 MB` superceding your setting. Are you sure, your settings are loaded? What's `phpinfo()` say?

Comment: In case you are not using a CGI PHP setup; have you restarted you web server to let the `php.ini` changes take effect?

Comment: Nope. Didn't restart the server yet. I suppose that's why.

Comment: @RegEdit Do the restart and tell us if it worked. If so, don't forget to accept the best answer or update your question.

Comment: Can I execute a restart via cPanel?

Comment: And Can I check phpinfo() via Cpanel?

Comment: @RegEdit Your own server: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Shared hosting: wait a couple of minutes. You need to put `phpinfo()` into a script and upload it then execute it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as far as I know, it has to be 96M (without the B)
Second, make sure you are editing the correct php.ini, and you are restarting the web server after the change (needed if PHP is loaded as an apache module for example).

And third, increasing the memory limit may resolve the problem, but it's best to check why 64M are not enough :)

Comment: Thanks. Its coming from simple_html_dom.php. Its a memory intensive scraper script. I'm just trying to get it to work in order to trace it back.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart apache? Sometimes it's necessary.

Comment: Not yet. Its shared hosting Bluehost account. Can I restart via cpanel?

Comment: @RegEdit Shared Hosting accounts won't let you arbitrarily restart the web server. That would affect *all* other users on that server. You'll have to wait a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. It might be because you're storing something very huge in some variable or selecting a lot of data from your mySQL table. You need to provide more information about your script because 64M is really sufficient to execute most of the processing.

Comment: I agree. Its not a problem on my hostgator setup. No issues. But on this bluehost box, with php 5.2.17, Its running up against a wall.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the comments, it's obvious you're on a shared hosting account.

Those usually don't let you edit your own `php.ini`, nor allow arbitrary limits to your pleasing. This would quickly take down the shared hosting server.